# Does monolithic link-time optimization work with static libraries?

Tags: llvm, link-time-optimization

[This article](http://johanengelen.github.io/ldc/2016/11/10/Link-Time-Optimization-LDC.html) discusses how object files can contain LLVM IR that is used for link-time optimization. But what if the linker is compiling a project that includes a static library, do static libraries have the information as well? If so, under which circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Static libraries can contain llvm-IR-bitcode also.

### A. Step for build static libs with llvm-IR-bitcode

1. In Xcode Static Lib Project:
   `Build Settings->Enable Bitcode` , Switch to `Yes`
2. `Product->Archive`

### B. Check if a static lib contains llvm-IR-bitcode or not.

1. `otool -l libDemo.a`
2. In the output, search for `__bitcode` and check whether the `size` is bigger than 000001 or not.
   if `size` > 000001 : then the static lib contain llvm-IR-bitcode
   else: the static lib do not contain llvm-IR-bitcode.

Wish this answers your question.

Comment: Does this mean bitcode needs to also be enabled for the object files that are being given to the linker?

Comment: It depends, If you need the bitcode been included in the final generated binary file, then, the answer is `yes`. If you just do something (maybe bitcode optimization just like I do), then you then answer is `no`.